# Why can't I update my class properties in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I'm making a Wizard game prototype and I came across an issue:

I created a class called Wizard and a class called Goblin:

```
class Wizard
{
    public:
        int damage;
        int health;
        int stamina;

        Wizard(int d, int h, int s)
        {
            d = damage;
            h = health;
            s = stamina;
        }

        float getDamage() { return damage; }
        void setDamage(int v) { v = damage; }

        float getHealth() { return health; }
        void setHealth(int v) { v = health; }

        float getStamina() { return stamina; }
        void setStamina(float v) { v = stamina; }

};

class Goblin
{
    public:
        int health;
        int damage;

        Goblin(int h, int d)
        {
            h = health;
            d = damage;
        }

        float getHealth() { return health; }
        void setHealth(int v) { v = health; }

        float getDamage() { return damage; }
        void setDamage(int v) { v = damage; }
};
```

Then, I declared and initialized variables for them:

```
Wizard wizard(50, 150, 10);
Goblin goblin(150, 25);
```

Then, I created an `attack()` function:

```
void attack(Wizard attacker, Goblin target)
{
    if(target.getDamage() > 0.0)
    {
        attacker.setStamina(attacker.getStamina() - 1);
    }
}
```

So, in the main function, I called attack and printed out the results:

```
int main()
{
    attack(wizard, goblin);
    printInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

But this is the result:

```
> clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
> ./main
Wizard Health: 0
Wizard Damage: 0
Wizard Stamina: 0

Goblin Damage: 0
Goblin Health: 0
```

I also created a `printInfo()` function:

```
void printInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Wizard Health: " << wizard.getHealth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wizard Damage: " << wizard.getDamage() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wizard Stamina: " << wizard.getStamina() << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Goblin Damage: " << goblin.getHealth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Goblin Health: " << goblin.getDamage() << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the full file if you need it:

```
#include <iostream>

class Wizard
{
    public:
        int damage;
        int health;
        int stamina;

        Wizard(int d, int h, int s)
        {
            d = damage;
            h = health;
            s = stamina;
        }

        float getDamage() { return damage; }
        void setDamage(int v) { v = damage; }

        float getHealth() { return health; }
        void setHealth(int v) { v = health; }

        float getStamina() { return stamina; }
        void setStamina(float v) { v = stamina; }

};

class Goblin
{
    public:
        int health;
        int damage;

        Goblin(int h, int d)
        {
            h = health;
            d = damage;
        }

        float getHealth() { return health; }
        void setHealth(int v) { v = health; }

        float getDamage() { return damage; }
        void setDamage(int v) { v = damage; }
};

Wizard wizard(50, 150, 10);
Goblin goblin(150, 25);

void attack(Wizard attacker, Goblin target);
void printInfo();

int main()
{
    attack(wizard, goblin);
    printInfo();

    return 0;
}

void attack(Wizard attacker, Goblin target)
{
    if(target.getDamage() > 0.0)
    {
        attacker.setStamina(attacker.getStamina() - 1);
    }
}

void printInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Wizard Health: " << wizard.getHealth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wizard Damage: " << wizard.getDamage() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wizard Stamina: " << wizard.getStamina() << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Goblin Damage: " << goblin.getHealth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Goblin Health: " << goblin.getDamage() << std::endl;
}
```

Sorry if this is very long, but help would be appreciated.

Comment: in the constructor you assign `h` to `health`, it should be the other way round. For the other fields, too.

Comment: The same in issue as mentioned by Raildex exists in the setters. I'm used to prefix member variables with `m_` which may help aviod confusion there. Btw: why do your getters return `float`? The member variables have int type and the setters take `int` too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructors and set* methods you need to assign input parameter values to the member variables of classes. Not vice versa.

```
#include <iostream>

class Wizard
{
    public:
        int damage;
        int health;
        int stamina;

        Wizard(int d, int h, int s)
        {
            damage = d;
            health = h;
            stamina = s;
        }

        float getDamage() { return damage; }
        void setDamage(int v) { damage = v; }

        float getHealth() { return health; }
        void setHealth(int v) { health = v; }

        float getStamina() { return stamina; }
        void setStamina(float v) { stamina = v; }

};

class Goblin
{
    public:
        int health;
        int damage;

        Goblin(int h, int d)
        {
            health = h;
            damage = d;
        }

        float getHealth() { return health; }
        void setHealth(int v) { health = v; }

        float getDamage() { return damage; }
        void setDamage(int v) { damage = v; }
};

Wizard wizard(50, 150, 10);
Goblin goblin(150, 25);

void attack(Wizard attacker, Goblin target);
void printInfo();

int main()
{
    attack(wizard, goblin);
    printInfo();

    return 0;
}

void attack(Wizard attacker, Goblin target)
{
    if(target.getDamage() > 0.0)
    {
        attacker.setStamina(attacker.getStamina() - 1);
    }
}

void printInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Wizard Health: " << wizard.getHealth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wizard Damage: " << wizard.getDamage() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wizard Stamina: " << wizard.getStamina() << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Goblin Damage: " << goblin.getHealth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Goblin Health: " << goblin.getDamage() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Ralidex already answered that. The values are getting printed, but not updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `attack()` function takes parameters by value. As such it modifies a copy of your global variables.

Use references:

```
void attack(Wizard& attacker, Goblin& target)
{
    ...
}
```

PS: see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor to learn about member initializer lists

Comment: You may want to mention the issue with the assignments being done in "reverse direction" in setters/constructors...

Comment: One lesson at a time 